# Automatically shorten living column title or have a linebreak

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

I have a long document that has several long chapters. Each chapter has a title which can be short or long (often it is very long). I noticed that if I use `\pagestyle{headings}` in the `scrreprt` class the long chapter titles extend into the page border.

Is there a solution to this? I could imagine 3 options (I don't want to do it manually)

1. Specify a length e.g. `2/3 \textwidth` after which living column title is stopped and the remaining text is replaced by ...
2. Have a linebreak in the columntitle of the page
3. Change the font size to a smaller font so that even long chapter titles fit.

Unfortunately, I could not find any hint on any of these options.

Here is a small example:

```
    \documentclass[paper=letter,openright,numbers=noenddot,BCOR=1cm,toc=listof,captions=tableheading,%
headsepline=off]{scrreprt} %twoside
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=classic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
\automark{chapter}
\chapter{Chapter with a short title}
\newpage
Some text...
\chapter{This is a chapter heading intended for the living column title with extra long text that includes many words that are short and long}
\newpage
Some text... and we notice that the living column title extends into the page border which is not nice.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is `\chapter[short title]{long title}` ok ?

Comment: You can use the optional argument of `\chapter[<short>]{<long>}`. `<short>` will be used in the ToC and the header. KOMA-Script also allows you to say `\chapter[head=<head-entry>,tocentry=<toc-entry>]{<long>}` to distinguish between them or set only one of them and use `<long>` for the other one.

Comment: @cgnieder Your comment looks very much like an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the optional argument of `\chapter`. In the standard classes as well as in the KOMA-Script classes such as `scrreprt` which you are using the syntax is as follows:

```
\chapter[<short entry>]{<long entry>}
```

This syntax also is valid for the other sectioning commands like `\section`, `\subsection` or `\part`. If the optional argument is omitted `<long entry>` is used for the actual heading as well as for the entry in the table of contents (toc) and the header. If the optional argument is used `<short entry>` is used for the toc entry and for the header while `<long entry>` is used for the actual heading.

KOMA-Script offers options to control how `<short entry>` is used:

- `headings=optiontohead` : `<short entry>` will only be used for the header and `<long entry>` will be used for toc and heading.
- `headings=optiontotoc` : `<short entry>` will only be used for the toc and `<long entry>` will be used for header and heading.
- `headings=optiontoheadandtoc` : the default setting as described above.

Each of these options activates an even finer control possibility via a key/value interface for the optional argument:

- `\chapter[tocentry=<toc>]{<heading>}` : `<toc>` will be used for the toc and `<heading>` both for header and heading.
- `\chapter[head=<header>]{<heading>}` : `<header>` will be used for the header and `<heading>` will be used both for the toc and the heading.
- `\chapter[head=<header>,tocentry=<toc>]{<heading>}` : `<header>` will be used for the header, `<toc>` will be used for the toc, and `<heading>` will be used for the heading.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to pursue the first strategy by using the [`truncate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/truncate).

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE Usually answers are presented in compilable MWE form. Suggestions that do not immediately solve the OP's problem most likely belong in the comments.